# Combine SQL query results where any are empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

I'm trying to get the bulk of my data cleaning taken care of using SQL queries. Sometimes we will just need a person to make the call, but in cases where, say, the only differences in data are ones where data is missing, I'd like to be able to just return a single row. Say we have the following data:

```
| FirstName | LastName | Email              | Phone     |
|:--------- |:-------- |:------------------ |:--------- |
| Joe       | Bloggs   | joe.bl@domain.com  | 9412 3456 |
| Bob       | Jones    | bob.jones@abc.com  | 9498 7654 |
| Bob       | Jones    | bob.jones@abc.com  |           |
| Mary      | Flubbs   |                    |           |
| Mary      | Flubbs   |                    | 9411 1111 |
| Mary      | Flubbs   | marymary@corp.com  |           |
| Taylor    | Minns    | taylor@minnsco.com | 9499 8877 |
| Taylor    | Minns    |                    | 9477 8899 |
| Taylor    | Minns    |                    |           |
```

Joe only has one record. Bob's records are identical except for a missing phone number.
Mary's also have no discrepancies, just empties. Taylor has two different phone numbers, and will therefore still need two records, like so:

```
| FirstName | LastName | Email              | Phone     |
|:--------- |:-------- |:------------------ |:--------- |
| Joe       | Bloggs   | joe.bl@domain.com  | 9412 3456 |
| Bob       | Jones    | bob.jones@abc.com  | 9498 7654 |
| Mary      | Flubbs   | marymary@corp.com  | 9411 1111 |
| Taylor    | Minns    | taylor@minnsco.com | 9499 8877 |
| Taylor    | Minns    | taylor@minnsco.com | 9477 8899 |
```

If I simply go `SELECT DISTINCT...` it will show empties. If I use `MAX()` or `MIN()` I'll lose data. Is there a way to collapse records down like this without losing distinct data?

Comment: Why are you using a `PROCEDURE` instead of a `FUNCTION` or `VIEW`? Generally speaking you should always prefer UDFs and Views to Sprocs because they're recomposable.

Comment: "Is there a way to collapse records down like this without losing distinct data?" - yegods, this is **not** how you're meant to handle database refactoring. You need to read-up on database normalization and fundamental database theory, such as [Codd's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_theorem) - and then start normalizing your database design and use separate `TABLE`s for each logical relation (a "relation" is not a "relationship" btw). If you need your data to be formatted like the old data for compatibility then use a `VIEW` to reconstitute normalized data into old table names.

Comment: Use `not exists` and check for a record which you consider similar.

Comment: @Dai I'm not sure whether I'm doing what you seem to suspect I am. I won't bother detailing the old data structure as it's a mess and is part of why we're re-building. In this particular case, I'm aiming for a person table, with child tables for such entities as employees, customer contacts etc etc. - Normalizing from the mess that came before. Sure, I'm going further than is absolutely necessary, but because of the way that single people often play multiple roles, and I don't want to expect my users to update multiple records when a single person's details change, I'm planning it that way.

Comment: Then why are there two records for `Taylor`

Comment: @Charlieface because there are two distinct phone numbers.

Comment: What would you do in the case of a 4th "Taylor  Minns" row with a different email address? Which email address would you associate with the blank email address against the different phone number?

Comment: This is what we're trying to tell you: you need a separate `PhoneNumber` table where you can store multiple phone numbers per person

Comment: @DaleK Any rows with the same names but any unique (except for empties) contact details of any kind (email or phone) should be retained. Those will need to be sorted later by a human being who can call the numbers/send to the emails to determine which is current. It might have been helpful for those people to know which was the most recently added, but creation timestamps are a new element I'll be adding into the database.

Comment: @Charlieface I'm open to it. But there does need to be something that differentiates records (and I'm thinking beyond a record ID) for common names. There are, for example, over 10 Chris Smiths in our contacts table alone, and most of those records are actually different people, which we can tell by the email address.

But that, too, is not the most reliable metric, so maybe I should ditch being able to tell person records apart without the relationships they have/their record IDs...

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `Cross Apply` or `Inner Join`. Assuming the same names are the same people

Cross Apply

```
declare @mytable table (Firstname varchar(50), LastName varchar(50), Email varchar(50), Phone varchar(50))

insert into @mytable
values 
('Joe'       , 'Bloggs'   , 'joe.bl@domain.com'  , '9412 3456') ,
('Bob'       , 'Jones'    , 'bob.jones@abc.com'  , '9498 7654') ,
('Bob'       , 'Jones'    , 'bob.jones@abc.com'  , '') ,
('Mary'      , 'Flubbs'   , ''                   , '') ,
('Mary'      , 'Flubbs'  ,  ''                  , '9411 1111') ,
('Mary'      , 'Flubbs'   , 'marymary@corp.com'  , '') ,
('Taylor'    , 'Minns'    , 'taylor@minnsco.com' , '9499 8877') ,
('Taylor'    , 'Minns'    ,  ''                  , '9477 8899') ,
('Taylor'    , 'Minns'    ,  ''                  ,  '')

select distinct firstname, lastname, x.Email, y.Phone
from @mytable t
cross apply (  -- this statement will only filter emails
    select email
    from @mytable  e
    where nullif(email,'') is not null
    and e.Firstname  = t.Firstname
    and e.LastName = t.LastName
) x
cross apply ( -- this statement will only filter phone
    select phone
    from @mytable p
    where nullif(phone,'') is not null
    and p.Firstname  = t.Firstname
    and p.LastName = t.LastName
) y
```

Inner Join

```
select distinct t.firstname, t.lastname, x.Email, y.Phone
from @mytable t
inner join (
    select Firstname, LastName, email
    from @mytable  e
    where nullif(email,'') is not null
) x on x.Firstname  = t.Firstname
    and x.LastName = t.LastName
inner join (
    select Firstname, LastName, phone
    from @mytable  p
    where nullif(phone,'') is not null
) y on y.Firstname  = t.Firstname
    and y.LastName = t.LastName
```

Comment: Care to add an explanation of how that works.

Comment: As much as I would like to @DaleK but I'm not doing this for livelihood so when I get a chance I will explain but this is not a complex `Cross Apply` statement so I reckon he can figure it out.

Comment: FYI, the point of this site is to explain, not just to provide working code. So all good answers should contain an explanation.

Comment: thanks but again this is not a complex sql query.

Comment: To you maybe, but many people asking on here have never come across `CROSS APPLY` let alone this method of using it.

Comment: And it strikes me it took you longer to create the DDL+DML than it would to explain how it works :) speaking of having work to do

Comment: @DaleK lol sorry mate. I'm between work and this :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` expression on `Email` and `Phone` to select between the current value (if there is one) or find a value for the current row if it's empty or null.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        FirstName
    ,   LastName
    ,   CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(p1.Email, '') = '' 
            THEN (
                    SELECT MAX(p2.Email) 
                    FROM Person p2
                    WHERE  
                        p1.FirstName = p2.FirstName 
                    AND p1.LastName  = p2.LastName 
                    AND ISNULL(p2.Email, '') <> ''
                )
            ELSE p1.Email 
        END Email 
    ,   CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(p1.Phone, '') = '' 
            THEN (
                    SELECT MAX(p2.Phone) 
                    FROM Person p2
                    WHERE  
                        p1.FirstName = p2.FirstName 
                    AND p1.LastName  = p2.LastName 
                    AND ISNULL(p2.Phone, '') <> ''
                )
            ELSE p1.Phone 
        END Phone 
    FROM 
        Person p1
) e 
GROUP BY 
    FirstName
,   LastName
,   Email
,   Phone
```

### [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/64533a/9)